# Laravel env and mailing info

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, laravel-mail

I want to know is that possible I use one of my host emails instead of gmail in laravel or not?

## Issues

1. When I use Gmail info as mailing

   ```
   MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
   MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
   MAIL_PORT=465
   MAIL_USERNAME=MAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com
   MAIL_PASSWORD=MAIL_PASSWORD
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
   MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@SITE.com
   MAIL_FROM_NAME="CUSTOM_NAME"
   ```

it works.

But when I try to use my host email it doesn't

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=HOSTING_SERVER
MAIL_PORT=HOST_PORT
MAIL_USERNAME=MY_HOST_EMAIL
MAIL_PASSWORD=MY_HOST_EMAIL_PASSPORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

2. Even with providing sender info in my `env` file emails **always send by gmail address** to users and not provided email address.

   ```
   MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@SITE.com
   MAIL_FROM_NAME="CUSTOM_NAME"
   ```

Any idea?

Comment: Are there any `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` variable in .env officially? Or you just added it yourself on the configuration file?

Comment: Did you run `php artisan config:cache` by any chance? If so, use `php artisan config:clear` to clear the cache or re-run the command to update the cache. It should pick up your changes then.

Comment: @bl4cksta it's official you can check it on `config/mail.php`

Comment: @Namoshek no that's not the case issue is somewhere else.